# Bayesian random slope model with divergent transitions. Help in setting stronger priors

Tags: bayesian, mixed-model, prior

I have a model with which I have convergence problems.

This are the model specifics (`brms` package):

```
 Family: gamma 
  Links: mu = log; shape = log 
Formula: Attesa ~ log(N.prest) + (log(N.prest) | Context) 
         shape ~ log(N.prest) + (log(N.prest) | Context)
   Data: TdA (Number of observations: 778) 
Samples: 8 chains, each with iter = 8000; warmup = 2000; thin = 1;
         total post-warmup samples = 48000; max_treedepth = 15, adapt_delta = .90
```

The dataset has just two observation per Context, for around 400 Contexts.

This is the results summary:

```
Group-Level Effects: 
~Context (Number of levels: 408) 
                                      Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Eff.Sample Rhat
sd(Intercept)                             1.10      0.10     0.91     1.27         89 1.06
sd(logN.prest)                            0.07      0.03     0.02     0.12         43 1.13
sd(shape_Intercept)                       0.81      0.20     0.41     1.25        997 1.01
sd(shape_logN.prest)                      0.06      0.05     0.00     0.18       1359 1.02
cor(Intercept,logN.prest)                -0.75      0.16    -0.97    -0.42       3767 1.00
cor(shape_Intercept,shape_logN.prest)    -0.16      0.55    -0.96     0.91       3552 1.00

Population-Level Effects: 
                 Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Eff.Sample Rhat
Intercept            2.62      0.08     2.46     2.79        334 1.02
shape_Intercept      0.32      0.21    -0.08     0.74       3996 1.00
logN.prest           0.08      0.01     0.05     0.10        733 1.01
shape_logN.prest     0.54      0.05     0.44     0.64        677 1.02

Samples were drawn using sampling(NUTS). For each parameter, Eff.Sample 
is a crude measure of effective sample size, and Rhat is the potential 
scale reduction factor on split chains (at convergence, Rhat = 1).
Warning messages:
1: The model has not converged (some Rhats are > 1.1). Do not analyse the results! 
We recommend running more iterations and/or setting stronger priors. 
2: There were 7996 divergent transitions after warmup. Increasing adapt_delta above 0.9 may help.
See http://mc-stan.org/misc/warnings.html#divergent-transitions-after-warmup
```

that shows how `sd(Intercept)`, `sd(logN.prest)` and many Context level specific random slopes and intercepts are particularly problematic.

These are the priors:

```
                  prior     class       coef   group resp  dpar nlpar bound
1        cauchy(0, 2.5)         b                                          
2                               b logN.prest                               
3                               b                         shape            
4                               b logN.prest              shape            
5          normal(0, 2) Intercept                                          
6   student_t(3, 0, 10) Intercept                         shape            
7  lkj_corr_cholesky(1)         L                                          
8                               L            Context                       
9        normal(0, 1.5)        sd                                          
10  student_t(3, 0, 10)        sd                         shape            
11                             sd            Context                       
12                             sd  Intercept Context                       
13                             sd logN.prest Context                       
14                             sd            Context      shape            
15                             sd  Intercept Context      shape            
16                             sd logN.prest Context      shape
```

Keeping in mind that I'm more interested in prediction (and prediction distribution) than parameter estimation, where can I put stronger priors to improve the model?

And a bonus,`brms`specific, question: are priors intended hierarchically? That is, is I set eg `set_prior('normal(0, 2), class = 'sd')`, is it applied to all sd parameters, even if in the `prior_summary()` output above they are blank?

Comment: Have you plotted some of transitions to see where the divergences occur?

Comment: How can I do it?